# Set UITextView in focus

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I have a UITextView that is editable on a parent view along with a few other things. How can I set the UITextView to focus when the parent view shows up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call `[textField becomeFirstResponder]` from the view's `willAppear` selector.